# JDBC executeQuery and updateRow won't work on a specific table

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have the following code:

```
package sql_updates;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;


public class Sql_updates {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        int gen_p = 1600;
        int gl_p = 400;

        Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@lbuchpsooraswat:1521:AXATEST";

        //properties for creating connection to Oracle database
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("user", "COMPOSER");
        props.setProperty("password", "COMPOSER");

        //creating connection to Oracle database using JDBC
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);

        Statement stmt = null;

        stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        HashSet hs = new HashSet();

        for (int i = 1; i <= gen_p; i++) {
            hs.add("#" + RandomStringUtils.random(7, true, true));

        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= gl_p; i++) {
            hs.add(RandomStringUtils.random(7, true, true));

        }

        ResultSet uprs = stmt.executeQuery(
                "SELECT ACC FROM table_p");

        Iterator<String> it = hs.iterator();
        int i = 0;
        while (uprs.next() && it.hasNext()) {

            String f = uprs.getString("ACC");

            uprs.updateString("ACC", it.next());
            uprs.updateRow();
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println("am terminat update-ul");

        stmt.executeUpdate(
                "INSERT INTO TABLE_G(TC, GACC, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9, P10, P11, P12, P13, P14, START_DATE, END_DATE) SELECT TC, ACC, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9, P10, P11, P12, P13, P14, START_DATE, END_DATE  FROM TABLE_P WHERE ACC LIKE '#%'");

stmt.close();
        System.out.println("am terminat INSERT-ul");
        stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);


        System.out.println("am terminat UPDATE-ul");


        HashSet hs2 = new HashSet();

        for (int j = 1; j <= 2000; j++) {
            hs2.add(RandomStringUtils.random(7, true, true));

        }

        Iterator<String> it2 = hs2.iterator();
        System.out.println("incep update-ul");
        uprs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ACC FROM table_g");


        int zz=1;
        while (uprs.next()) {
            String f = uprs.getString("ACC");
            uprs.updateString("ACC", RandomStringUtils.random(7, true, true));
            uprs.updateRow();
            zz++;
            if(zz%100==0)
            System.out.println("aaaaa   "+zz);
        }

        stmt.close();
        con.close();

        System.out.println("am terminat update-ul");
    }

}
```

My problem is that even tough the first insert in my table_g is working correctly, the updateRow part gets blocked without any error message and I don't understand why... The thing I don't get to understand is that sometimes it stops somewhere around 1600, or 4500, or sometimes it doesn't get to print anything but it gets stuck and does nothing more. I thought it might be something related to my table_g, but why does the insert work then? Even more, when I try directly stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE TABLE_G SET ACC='X'"); The same thing, it is freezing. Can you please help me?

Thanks!

P.S.: Sorry for the unorganized code :)

Comment: Your code is actually nicely laid out.  You can try wrapping that `stmt.executeUpdate()` call in a try catch block, or use the debugger and see what is happening.  This should reveal the root cause.

Comment: Do you have constraints like a `PRIMARY KEY` in `table_p` that include the `ACC` column you're trying to update?

Comment: You need to wrap your code in try catch blocks to know what is actually happening. How do you know that updateRow is getting blocked? Have you used debugger for this? If yes, then you might know what is causing failure. However code looks good. You need to post more information, so that we can help!

Comment: No PRIMARY KEYS

Comment: @RishiPandey - In my while loop I have printed this  " if(zz%100==0)
            System.out.println("aaaaa   "+zz);" to show me where I am with my updates. The thing I don't get to understand is that sometimes it stops somewhere around 1600, or 4500, or sometimes it doesn't get to print anything but it gets stuck and does nothing more. I thought it might be something related to my table_g, but why does the insert work then? Even more, when I try directly  stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE TABLE_G SET ACC='X'"); The same thing, it is freezing.

Comment: Is it necessary to open the statement here as ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE? It actually means the ResultSet is sensitive to changes to the underlying data. If there is any modification is going on your update may block.